# How do I open an App Store link without starting the App Store app?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac-appstore

When I search Google for an app, for example "Wakeout!", I get this search result:

> [image]

When I click on it, this alert opens up:

> [image]

I click Cancel, I don't want to open the App Store. But this is what I end up getting:
[image]

And now I'm stuck here. How can I display the page without starting the App Store app with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. You must mark the "Always allow apps.apple.com to open links of this type in the associated app" checkbox and click "Cancel" button. Then it will stop appearing.

Comment: Where can I find that checkbox? Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: This is not working (anymore).